# Criando rotas (controller/id/action) no c#

Tags: c#, controller, route, actions

Estou tentando criar uma rota bem específica em uma página do meu projeto.
Como é de costume, as rotas no .NET são `controller/action/id` porém em uma página específica eu gostaria que fosse `controller/id/action`.

O que eu consegui foi:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Produto",
    url: "Produto/{name}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Produto", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z\.]{3,20}$" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = @"^((?!Perfil).*)" }
);
```

Então, a url /Produto/carro/Ver funciona perfeitamente. 
A url /Campanha/Editar/1 também funciona perfeitamente.

**Porém**, se for chamada a url /Produto/carro (SEM BARRA NO FINAL) não está funcionando. Não está indo para a action Index. Tentei utilizar o código abaixo, mas não deu certo.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProdutoIndex",
    url: "Produto/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Produto", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z\.]{3,20}$" }
);
```

Gostaria que funcionasse sem a barra no final, pois obrigar o usuário a colocar essa barra é muito ruim.

Comment: Por que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: Foi requisitado pelo cliente que a url seja assim. 
A questão de não ter uma barra no final quando a url for `/Produto/{name}` é um capricho meu. E também, acho que se o usuário for escrever a url na mão, ele não vai por a barra no final, assim tomando um 404 na cara.

Comment: você tentou colocar as duas rotas.?

Comment: sim. eu coloquei todas as rotas. na ordem: 1 - name: "ProdutoIndex", 2 - name: "Produto", 3 - name: "Default".